# Traverse up a directed graph in c# (DAG)

Tags: c#, recursion, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a simple graph without cycles/Multiple edges.

Its always pointing down.

[image]

I have a list of edge instances and they are sorted top to down according to their appearance in the graph image. I do not know whether that is important for you. I just thought how would you know what is the node at the bottom of the graph?!

```
class Edge
{
   public string FromNodeId {get; set;}
   public string ToNodeId{get; set;}
}

class Node
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

I need to traverse **UP** the graph due to certain business logic.

1. What is the algorythm called when I need to visit every node in a recursive way?
2. What could be a starting point to iterate the list of edges recursively up the graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the browsing methode of a graph from bottom to top.

you need to initialize it with your last element.

```
            class Edge
            {
                public int FromNodeId { get; set; }
                public int ToNodeId { get; set; }
            }
            class Node // nodes from 0 or 1 to infinit
            {
                public int Id { get; set; }
                public string Name { get; set; }
            }

            void fromBottom(List<Edge> Edges,List<Node> Nodes, Node current)  
            {
                var willVisit = Edges.Where(x => x.ToNodeId == current.Id).ToList();
                if (willVisit.FirstOrDefault()==null)
                {
                    // do your stuff for the last node
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(var nd in willVisit)
                    {
                        fromBottom(Edges, Nodes,Nodes.Where(x=>x.Id==nd.FromNodeId).First());
                    }
                }
            }
```

here is the browsing methode of a graph from top to bottom.

```
            void fromTop(List<Edge> Edges,List<Node> Nodes, Node current)  
            {
                var willVisit = Edges.Where(x => x.FromNodeId == current.Id).ToList();
                if (willVisit.FirstOrDefault()==null)
                {
                    // do your stuff for the last node 
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(var nd in willVisit)
                    {
                        fromTop(Edges, Nodes,Nodes.Where(x=>x.Id==nd.ToNodeId).First());
                    }
                }
            }
```

note : to avoid visiting a node several times, you can add a boolean variable in your structure to validate the visit and check it later in the foreach loop.

Comment: Hi Amine, thansk for the help. The code works in that manner that the graph is traversing only a single possible path like: R, Q, M, L, G, E, B,A but the code does not iterate through all the possible ways from R,Q,N,L or  R,Q,O,L or R,Q,P,L .

Comment: I am not sure wether my comment above is right. I am still debugging a big graph and it takes ages maybe in 10 minutes I visit those above 3 possible path (rofl). Has this something to do with your NOTE about visiting a node several times? In debugging mode I can also continue debugging  from this traversal but the process never comes back to my visual studio... which is busy with CPU 18% .

Comment: Maybe a better hint what should work is: From Node L I go left to J, but it should also work to go up to Node G and H.

Comment: hello, for the visiting a node several times, i didn't add the condition for it, and for missing visiting all the possible ways, it's impossible because inside the loop foreach you have all nodes which have "fromNodeId" so it's impossible miss some nodes

Comment: please check the list of Edges

Comment: So you say the first time I reach the top of my graph: if (willVisit.FirstOrDefault() == null)
I should exit the method?

Comment: yes because, the  if (willVisit.FirstOrDefault() == null) it's the condition for stopping the recursivity.

Comment: No the return will not stop the recursion, it just continued in the foreach and it never ended. even after 5 minutes my visual studio is still running in debug mode.

Comment: thx worked my vs2019 was somehow broken...